# Similar MVC actions called by javascript, AntiForgery works on one, not the other

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a javascript function I use to do an Ajax call to my controller function. The javascript is generic enough I can use it for multiple controls. I have two areas that use the script. One works, one doesn't. I believe it's the footprint of the MVC controller that is being called.

The javascript looks like this:

```
$(Document).on("click",".delete-link",function (event) {
    var deleteLink = $(this);
    deleteLink.hide();
    var confirmButton = deleteLink.siblings(".delete-confirm");
    confirmButton.show();

    var cancelDelete = function () {
        removeEvents();
        showDeleteLink();
    };

    var deleteItem = function () {
        removeEvents();
        confirmButton.hide();
        var url = '/' + confirmButton.attr('data-delete-controller') + '/' + confirmButton.attr('data-delete-action') + '/' + confirmButton.attr('data-delete-id');
        $.post(
            url,
            AddAntiForgeryToken({ id: confirmButton.attr('data-delete-id') }))
           .done(function () {
               var parentRow = deleteLink.closest(".removable-row");//"tr:first, li:first");
               parentRow.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                   parentRow.remove();
               });
           }).fail(function (data) {
               alert("error");
           });
        return false;
    };

    var removeEvents = function () {
        confirmButton.off("click", deleteItem);
        $(document).on("click", cancelDelete);
        $(document).off("keypress", onKeyPress);
    };

    var showDeleteLink = function () {
        confirmButton.hide();
        deleteLink.show();
    };

    var onKeyPress = function (e) {
        //Cancel if escape key pressed
        if (e.which == 27) {
            cancelDelete();
        }
    };

    confirmButton.on("click", deleteItem);
    $(document).on("click", cancelDelete);
    $(document).on("keypress", onKeyPress);

    return false;
});

AddAntiForgeryToken = function (data) {
    data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    return data;
};
```

So the MVC view and controller action that work are defined like this:

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomFieldOptionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomFieldId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SortOrder, new { @class = "SortOrder" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsActive)

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OptionLabel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OptionLabel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OptionLabel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn delete-link" />
        <div class="btn btn-primary delete-confirm" style="display: none"
             data-delete-id="@Model.CustomFieldOptionId"
             data-delete-controller="customforms"
             data-delete-action="_OptionEditorRowDelete">Confirm Delete</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("_OptionEditorRowDelete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult _OptionEditorRowDelete(int id)
{
    var custFieldOption = db.CustomFieldOptions.Find(id);
    if (custFieldOption == null) return null;
    custFieldOption.IsActive = false;
    db.Entry(custFieldOption).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return null;
}
```

The one that is not working is defined like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ProfileId)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProfileIdentifierValue)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsPrimary)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "profileemailsedit", new { id = item.ProfileIdentifierId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "_ProfileEmailsDelete", new { id = item.ProfileIdentifierId }, new { @class = "delete-link" })
            <a class="delete-link" href="@Url.Action("_ProfileEmailsDelete", new { id = item.ProfileIdentifierId })">Delete</a>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn delete-link" />
            <div class="btn btn-primary delete-confirm" style="display: none"
                 data-delete-id="@item.ProfileIdentifierId"
                 data-delete-controller="profiles"
                 data-delete-action="_ProfileEmailsDelete">Confirm Delete</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult _ProfileEmailsDelete(int id)
{
    var profIdentifier = db.ProfileIdentifier.Find(id);
    if (profIdentifier == null) return null;
    profIdentifier.IsActive = false;
    db.Entry(profIdentifier).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

    return null;
}
```

As you can see the controllers are very similar. However, the _ProfileEmailsDelete get's this javascript error:

> POST http://localhost:63595/profiles/_ProfileEmailsDelete/168 500 (Internal Server Error)

Part of the server 500 error is:

> [HttpAntiForgeryException]: The required anti-forgery form field
>   "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.    at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken,
>   AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)    at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext)    at System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate()

I'm not sure why the AntiForgery works with one and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error is your ajax response from the server, not your javascript.  The actual problem is not jumping out at me, but most often when I have seen this type of behavior it ends up being something in the view rendering that causes it.  For example trying to reference the values of a collection that is null in the view would act this way.  Using the traffic analyzer features of the browser developer tools can sometimes help shed light on the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first example was in a partial view. The parent view had this:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

I added that to the View for the second example, and then the javascript could properly get the token to pass back with the $.post command.